# How using javascript can i save a PDF from inside a frame with a html5 <embed> tag

Tags: javascript, ios, html, pdf

I have a website which dynamically creates a PDF after some user selection in one of its frames. It uses the HTML5  tag to display the PDF file.

Can someone help me with a script which:

- detect when a pdf is loaded (do we need to determine the frame first?)
- save the pdf to a local storage location (iOS)

Comment: iOS has this feature built in... why reinvent the wheel? Are you trying to automate the process?

Comment: As when PDF is displayed in the web view  want to download it to extract its data and yes it should be automated. In fact once detection and saving has taken place the web view will be removed from view and user forwarded to new view controller to use data within the dissected PDF

Comment: Are you trying to scrape the PDF for data? Or are you trying to save the PDF to the iPhone's HDD? Saving the PDF to the HDD is not possible without user interaction for security reasons.

Comment: The PDF is dynamically generated and displayed in a frame using the <embed> tag. It contains all up-to-date last-minute information required for the purpose. I want to take the data from the PDF, use it to complete various workflows, like retrieving some additional information, completing logs, etc. The workflows are completed within the app being developed. I want the user to be presented the data from the PDF in these workflows, so I must extract them. In order to do this I presumed the file had to be saved locally to then be used for such purpose.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. What are you intending to DO with the generated PDF? Save to HDD or scrape for data?

Comment: I edited the post above...

Comment: PDF shouldn't be used as a data transfer agent. Since you are dynamically creating the PDF with the data, why not source the data from its origin?

Comment: Because it is not me who generates the PDF, I'm merely the end user for whom the PDF is generated wishing to use its included information in a better way...
Presently the only way to 'use' it is to print the PDF...

Answer (score 0):

To scrape a PDF for data, may I suggest you look into this lib from Mozilla:

https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/

With this, you should be able to load the PDF from a URL and then scrape the necessary data from that PDF without it ever needing to touch "local storage." Here is a link to a Hello World example to get you started:

http://jsbin.com/pdfjs-helloworld-v2/1/edit

> **Note:**
>   In web parlance, local storage refers to the browser's LocalStorage API which is not related to saving to the device's HDD.

Comment: Thanks for that. I will look at it now. But the first problem remains: determine **when** a PDF is loaded into the frame which can on other occasions host other HTML data like a table. **When** it is loading a PDF I want to then scrape the data, I would imagine by dynamically retrieving its src attribute and using it to open the file through pfdjs?

Comment: Right... You could set an `onLoad()` event for that frame and determine if the loaded content is a PDF by the extension name. One caveat, is your PDF on the same domain in which you are running this script?

Comment: Was hoping to execute the script through the iOS WebView usage

Comment: Are you coding in Obj-C? Thats a horse of a different color!

Comment: Yes, the .jsp page loaded inside the webview consists of:
<html>
 <head>
 <frameset...>
  <frameset...>
  <frame name"aaa" src="bbb.jsp"...>
   #document
    <html>
     <body>
      <embed name="plugin" src="https://www......." type="application/pdf">
     </body>
    </html>
  </frame>
  <iframe ....>
  </frameset>
 </html>